# What is the missing number and the correct sequence?

Tags: mathematics, sequence

I have a riddle, you might wanna help solve.

> Just imagine, we would like to change the sequence (that works very well now [in German there is the term "funktioniert 1A" - which translates into somewhat like "works optimally" and which could be a clue]) of the following numbers. What could that sequence be?
>
> 84474, 349272, 1284192, 6648480, 24948000, 63504000, 97511040, 240166080
>
> Additionally, one number is missing! Please tell me which one and include it into the sequence I'm searching for!

Comment: [I could just fit a polynomial and extrapolate from that...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKA4w2O61Xo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

> 84474, 240166080, 6648480, 1284192, 63504000, 349272, 5027400, 97511040, 24948000

Explanation:

> Step 1: Perform integer factorization for each number
>  Step 2: Convert each integer to a letter 1A (1=A)
>  Step 3: Each number corresponds to a "starter" Pokémon
>  Step 4: Find the missing one, convert to number
>  Step 5: Sort alphabetically

Comment: Why is this the solution? Please [edit] your answer to explain.

Comment: Could you demonstrate your Step 3 with an example breakdown please? I'm struggling to follow your process and am probably not the only one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

The second series fits the function

g(x) = (29*x^7 - 694*x^6 + 6560*x^5 - 31150*x^4 + 77711*x^3 - 94876*x^2 + 46740*x + 46080)/720

When you insert the values 0 - 7 for x, then the values of the series are emitted in ascending order, but you write, that the order may be other than given. When inserting the value 8, then the result is 546, which might be the result that you are looking for!